# Cakephp: how to call javascript function in link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

In Html,

```
<a href="some_url"> Contact Seller </a>
```

In Cakephp,

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Contact Seller', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'contactseller', 'full_base'=>true)); ?>
```

But i am having trouble in converting the following html to Cakephp:

```
<a href="some_url" onClick="return popup(this, 'popup_name')">my popup</a>
```

The following is a popup javascript method:

```
function popup(mylink, windowname) {
if (! window.focus)
  return true;

var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
  href=mylink;
else
  href=mylink.href;

window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false; 
}
```

How do i convert the html to Cakephp?

```
<a href="some_url" onClick="return popup(this, 'popup_name')">my popup</a>
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a href="some_url" onClick="return popup(this, 'popup_name')">my popup</a>
```

would convert to this in CakePHP:

```
$this->Html->link('my popup', 'some_url', ['onclick' => 'return popup(this, "popup_name")']);
```

FYI, You can put any attribute in the third argument of the link() method.  The documentation on [creating links](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links) is pretty extensive and gives examples.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Now i see how "Link" works in Cake.